# Is their a way to compile a project so that all your functions classes ect. go into one file that you can link?

Tags: c++, compilation

So I was wondering if I had a project that had a bunch of useful functions in it if their would be a way to make some sort of library for these funcions.  For example I have like ShaderLoader.h, ShaderLoader.cpp, MyMath.h, MyMath.cpp ect.  Is their some way to make these compile so that instead of adding alllll of those file into each new project I could simply link a file.  Perhaps a .dll?  BTW my project is in c++.

Also what would happen to the main function if I did so?  And would variables work the same way?

Thanks much!

Comment: It depends so much on your platform (what OS, what compiler)

Comment: Afaik, you could just create a header that includes all your other headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the best way is to create a library (.dll or .a), your main will work the same, in your project that should use this library add `-Ipath to headers` and `-Lpath_to_thelibrary -llibraryname`, if the library name is libCustomLib, you should write `-lCustomLib`

Comment: What should I do if i made a .dll and their were functions I didn't want to be able to see.  Such as a function that is only called once that initializes opengl libraries.  Is their a way to hide it without putting it in a class?

Comment: No. But you can declare it as private, like that you can call it only from within the class itself only and it will be not usable by no one else

Answer (score 2):

If you have many `.cpp` files without `main` function in it and one `cpp` file with `main` that uses `function` of other `.cpp` files then one possible way is to link `object` file of other files with `main` file at compile time.

Example - 
Suppose you are having 2 `.cpp` files ,

First one is `add.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
 void add()
 {
   int a,b;
   std::cout<<"\nEnter two numbers";
   std::cin>>a>>b;
   std::cout<<"Sum is : "<<a+b;
 }
```

Compile it you will get an error `undefined reference to WinMain` and you will get `add.o` file in your project folder.

And second one is `mul.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
 void mul()
 {
   int a,b;
   std::cout<<"\nEnter two numbers";
   std::cin>>a>>b;
   std::cout<<"Mul is : "<<a*b;
 }
```

Compile it again you will get an error `undefined reference to WinMain` and you will get `mul.o` file in your project folder.
Now if you want to use both functions in your new project/code then you will just need to link `add.o` and `mul.o` to your project instead of adding `add.cpp` and `mul.cpp` to project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

 void add();
 void mul();

 int main()
 {
   int a;
   std::cout<<"Press \n1 - Addition\n2 - Multiplication\n";
   std::cin>>a;
   if(a==1)
   {add();}
   else if(a==2)
   {mul();}
   else
   {std::cout<<"Wrong choice";}
   return 0;
 }
```

This is just a example , in this way you can link your files instead of adding.